# set card to Listview

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter.
Please help me out with card to list view.
I'm getting data from SQLite and set that to listview directly. Please let me know how to add card in my code.
Here's my code.

```
 body: FutureBuilder<List<UserModel>>(
    future: db.getUserModelData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData)
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

      return ListView(
        children: snapshot.data
            .map((user) => ListTile(
                  title: Text(user.name),
                  subtitle: Text(user.bDate),
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Color(
                            (math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF)
                                    .toInt() <<
                                0)
                        .withOpacity(1.0),
                    child: Text(user.name[0],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )),
                  ),
                ))
            .toList(),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what you need?

Comment: @SelimKundakçıoğlu I want to add card to my this list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem with Column()
Here's the code

```
return Column(
            children: List.generate(snapshot.data.length, (itemIndex) {
              ProfileModel product = snapshot.data[itemIndex];
              return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                leading: SizedBox(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Color(
                              (math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF)
                                      .toInt() <<
                                  0)
                          .withOpacity(1.0),
                      child: Text(product.name[0],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )),
                    )),
                title: Text(product.name),
                subtitle: Text(product.bDate + ', ' + product.mobile),
              ));
            }),
          );
```